# How to find a steady state vector for a non-regular markov process?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, steady-state

I know that a non-regular markov process doesn't exactly converge towards a steady state, however the question is asking me to find the steady state vector of a given transition matrix (using online calculators) anyway.

What would be the most general way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The question is based on the Ehrenfest urns model where we can only move one ball at a time. It provides me with a matrix consisting of the probabilities of moving one ball at a time between two urns, however some probabilities are zero. Because of this, the Markov process is non-regular-- and so based off this information the question wants me to find the steady state vector.

Would it be just like finding the regular steady state, where I would use 
(T'-S|0)?

Comment: Could you give a more specific example of what you are trying to solve

Comment: @PMF Edited the question! Although now that I think about it... I might be overcomplicating things. It doesn't matter whether its a regular or non-regular process since we can find the steady state either way right? Non-regular would just mean that it never converges to it?